# REASSIGN OWNED to IAM service account

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have an application with a Postgres CloudSQL instance where the tables were set up by a developer's IAM account. Thus they are owned by that IAM account, and I'd now like to set them so they are owned by a IAM service account instead. However, I'm having a hard time getting `REASSIGN OWNED` to work, just getting permission issues instead.

I found this [somewhat similar documentation entry](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues#about-the-cloudsqlexternalsync-user) on how to reassign ownership by doing `GRANT "user@domain" TO "serviceaccount@project.iam"`. However, as soon as I do this, the service account is no longer able to log in, getting `FATAL:  Cloud SQL IAM user authentication failed for user serviceaccount@project.iam`. Revoking the grant allows login again, but I'm then unable to reassign ownership...

When testing on a separate instance, I did get the procedure to work between user accounts, and also from a service account to a user account, but not user account to service account.

Is there a either a way for a service account to be able to log in while GRANTed on the user account, or some other way to do ownership reassignments?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same, but this seems to reliably work:

Assuming you are logged in as `postgres`.

```sql
GRANT "serviceaccount@project.iam" TO postgres;
GRANT other_user TO postgres;

REASSIGN OWNED BY other_user TO "serviceaccount@project.iam";

REVOKE "other_user" FROM postgres;
-- If wanted DROP ROLE other_user;
REVOKE "serviceaccount@project.iam" FROM postgres;
```

Remember that `REASSIGN` works on a database level, so you potentially need to run this in each database where you want to transfer ownership.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot! I struggled with the same problem and was missing the last bit of information regarding `REASSIGN` working on a database level. Care to drop a source for that?